# Determining if a criteria reduces scatter

Tags: estimation, t-test

I'm stuck on deciding what would be the best approach for my current problem:

I have an array of approximately 1500 data points and I'm trying to find a best fit line through these points based on an complex expression with two free parameters. I found those parameters with Matlab's *lsqcurvefit* function and I calculate the r squared to be approximately 0.7 after fitting the line. My next step is to impose a criteria to the original dataset, which reduces the number of valid data to ~ 400. Since the criteria is one of the basic assumptions for the theory behind the dataset, I expect to see a "reduction" in the scatter, i.e. increase in r squared.

First thing that came to mind was doing the fitting procedure again on the reduced dataset and then comparing the two new fitting parameters with the old ones (theory doesn't say anything about the default or best values of the parameters). However, this doesn't say anything about the scatter. Regarding this, I've looked at [this link](http://www.graphpad.com/support/faqid/1765/), which describes using a t-test to compare the values of the parameters. However, the sample sizes need to be approximately the same which isn't true in my case (1500 <-> 400).

Comment: 'criteria' is plural. If there's only one, its a *criterion*. What form does your criterion take?

Comment: The criterion is basically a stationarity test (reverse arrangement test), the goal is to remove the non-stationary portion from the original dataset and then observe does the theory apply better as one would expect. When I plot my full dataset, and overlay the stationary portion with a different color, it's evident that the stationary portion includes lot less outliers and on average concentrates around the original best fit.